# Getting file info (out-of date, needs resolve) with P4 command line client

Tags: command-line, perforce

P4V provides information about each checked out file such as whether it is at the latest revision (out-of-date files have a yellow circle), and whether it needs to be resolved (question mark). Is there a way to get this info using the P4 command line client?

I've tried "p4 describe " and "p4 status", but these do not provide the info I'm looking for. Describe lists which revision each file is at, but not whether it is at the latest revision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see whether a file needs to be synced:

```
p4 sync -n FILE
```

To see whether a file needs to be resolved:

```
p4 resolve -n FILE
```

To see whether a file is open:

```
p4 opened FILE
```

To see all the revisions of a file:

```
p4 filelog FILE
```

etc

You can also do:

```
p4 fstat <flags> FILE
```

to get a giant dump of information about a file (formatted for easy parsing into a dictionary rather than human readability).

For a full list of commands, see:

```
p4 help commands
```

For more information on a particular command:

```
p4 help COMMAND
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to get this info for all the files in a pending changelist? For example, If I have a change with 30 files in it, and I want to make sure that they are all up-to-date, it would be a hassle to go through each file and type "p4 sync -n FILE".

Comment: You can also do tricky things like pipe the output of `opened` into `sync`, but 99% of the time you want to either sync the entire workspace (`p4 sync`) or at least the entire working directory (`p4 sync ...`) rather than individually syncing a bunch of files.  For open files, syncing automatically schedules resolves, which will then be displayed by `p4 resolve -n`.  Do `p4 resolve -as` to auto-resolve everything where the answer is obvious, `p4 resolve -am` if you trust automerge to do everything, and `p4 resolve` to go through each file interactively.

Comment: That makes sense. It's a different workflow than I'm used to with P4V (Where it shows you all the out-of-date files without having to sync), but I don't see any harm in doing an extra sync before committing. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yup: `p4 sync` is a no-op if everything is up to date, and if any files aren't up to date they need to be synced before you can submit, so might as well just do the sync.  :)